# unable to import django

Tags: python, django, import

[the error that is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWaIk.png)

I have installed the django version 3.0.2 all running but idk what could be the problem

Comment: You need to make sure that django is installed for that specific python interpreter

Comment: As per @Hippolippo comment, if you open a new Terminal window in your IDE and install django in there, and then try again, it should be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to happen when you have more than one Python installation.

Since you're working in VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings and choose 'Extensions.' Scroll down to "Python Path" and enter the path to the Python executable for 3.0.2. You should be able to import any packages you've installed for python.

Alternatively, you could (and should consider) creating a virtual environment, so that once you're in that environment, you can assume that the one python interpreter you've chosen for that environment is the one that you're using, once you've activated the environment.

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this.

1. You have multiple python versions and that you have not installed the Django on the version you are using with vscode.
2. Libraries folder is not added to environment path.
3. You might have misspelled `Django` in the pip command. Try `pip install Django==3.0.2`.

Check if these helps. I will add more possible reason if I can recollect them.